# First "numbers" count nouns is plural or singular?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, countability

So I have this line of sentence:

> This only applies to the first 100 people signing up.

When I see the word "applies", I am confused, is "first 100" plural, or singular? Or it should've been "apply"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subject is *this*, which is singular, so the verb is singular (*applies*).

The thing which is plural "the first 100 people signing up" is not the subject or even the direct object, but the indirect object of *applies*. In English, verbs agree only with their subject, not with any other argument.

Comment: Oh, ok then. That means the rest ("the first 100 people signing up") is just noun. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes. "The first 100 people signing up" is a (complex) noun phrase, functioning as indirect object of _applies_..